# Order my accounts by recent activity

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, sorting

On the profile page, it would be fine if the accounts could be ordered by recent activity.

I have 10 accounts across the Stack Exchange network and was recently very active in an account with a low number of reputation. This account is thus not in the top 5 and I have to use the "view more"-button. An ordering button seems somehow to be more user-friendly though.

I would propose order buttons (as already found in other profile sections) for reputation (default), activity and perhaps inbox.

Comment: _recent activity_ is vague, will an account that spent hours answering/commenting and being active will appear second just because you log in in another account? if not, how should recent activity be calculated? It is harder than it looks, but if developers are like me, they will like this kind of challenge

Comment: @ajax333221 That would be (to me) any trigger that posts an item to your `Activity` tab on the profile page. It's already labeled as such, so I don't see it as much of a stretch to use that data.

Comment: I also have this problem because I started a bounty on one of my sites and I have around another 10 sites with 101 reputation. Can we do something about it for more attention?